# Delete unknown amount of regexps using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to get a bunch of regular expressions for a file (one per line) and then fit those regexps into something like this `/$regexp/d` . I'm trying it this way:

```
while read line;do sed "/$line/d" to_delete.file >> output;done < to_delete.txt
```

But it says me 'unknown command', even if I change the delimiter.

**--- EDIT**

The `to_delete.txt` file has slashes but i'm already scraping them and that's where i find the error.

Comment: What are the contents of `to_delete.txt`?

Comment: FYI, your output file won't have all the lines deleted. It will have multiple copies of the input file, each copy just has one set of lines deleted.

Comment: You almost certainly have a `/` somewhere in your `to_delete.txt` which is breaking your regex.

Comment: right, I forgot to say, they are regexp matching urls (so it has slashes), I tried with \/ for every slash and also don't work. But it does if I try one by one.

Comment: You have to make sure that the delimiter you use doesn't appear in any of the lines. If you can't do that, you have to escape the delimtiers in `$line` before you substitute it.

Comment: @Barmar  I'm already scapping slashes from input file, but it doesn't work neither.

Comment: You need to show us the contents of this file. You probably need to escape something else. Also, as Barmar says, your code probably won't do what you think it does.

Comment: FFS, do some debugging: `echo "$line"`

Comment: @VdeVatman Show the code you're using to escape the slashes.

Comment: @Barmar I'm keeping it simple and I'm using literal regular expressions such as `http:\/\/www.someweb.com\/`

Comment: Please just post the contents of the file in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid problem with `/` in regex `sed` is allow to use another separator, so you can use e.g. `sed "\|$line|d"`.
Secondary if you put script into double-quotes you shoud add space between address range and action e.g. `"\|$line| d"`
But I see a general mistake in the script. The loop will print into `output` all `to_delete.file` (exept 1 line with regexp) by each loop. I suppose it is not the thing what OP wants.
If you'd like to exclude content of `to_delete.txt` from `to_delete.file` it can be easy done by `grep`

```
grep -vFf "to_delete.txt" "to_delete.file" > output
```

Comment: How does sed allow to use another separator when you aren't using s/// command? If i try with //d it also says 'unknown command' (but when i try with s/// it works fine).

Comment: @VdeVatman Sure, you free to use other separator in `s`ubstitute command like `s|||` without any preparation but if you use other separator in address range you have to escape first of them `\& & d`